# VBA <> function is not working as expected

Tags: excel, vba

I am comparing two cells that contain numbers either 1, 2, 3, or 4.
Inside a loop, I compare these integers from both cells. If they do not match (<>) then perform an Exit for next.
VBA ignores my code and continues through the loop. Using debug I see this.
This is basic logic laws. Any thoughts?

hdv = a number 1 to 4
adv = a number 1 to 4
row is a loop 1 to 100

```
      For loop= 1 To 100
                hdv = Worksheets("20002018").Cells(row, 1).Value
                    adv = Worksheets("20002018").Cells(row, 2).Value
                        If hdv <> adv Then Exit For
```

' if false perform some stuff here.
        Next loop

Worksheets("20002018").Cells(row, 1) contains 1 Worksheets("20002018").Cells(row, 2) contains 2
comparing these two values should be enough to exit the loop

Comment: As pointed out below - your posted code will not even compile, so it cannot fail when run...

Answer (score 1):

Your code will not compile when `loop` is used as the increment in the For ... Next. `Loop` is a reserved word in VBA and has another purpose.

Whatever you change it to, the same should probably be used instead of `row` in,

```
hdv = Worksheets("20002018").Cells(row, 1).Value
adv = Worksheets("20002018").Cells(row, 2).Value
```

Changing `row` to whatever numerical variable you use to increment the loop will increase the referenced row on the worksheet for each iteration of the For ... Next loop until it exits.

```
dim LOOPS as long, hdv as long, adv as long

for LOOPS =1 to 100
  hdv = Worksheets("20002018").Cells(LOOPS, 1).Value
  adv = Worksheets("20002018").Cells(LOOPS, 2).Value
  If hdv <> adv Then Exit For

   'other stuff

Next LOOPS
```

Comment: Sorry - 'Loops' & 'row'  was just a variable used for clarification here. In the program I used lps & hrw and arw.